# Maven: plugin to download a single file from shared folder

Tags: maven, samba

In our Company we develop a project, managed by Maven3, in which we have to include some docs, tutorials, sample files, etc...

These files are produced by people who are not part of the development team, and they do not want fiddle around with any sort of VCS, nor project management/build tools like Maven. They just want to upload a **zip** file with everything inside, into a shared folder.

And that's it. From there, we have to do the rest.

So far I've managed to tell Maven, using exec-maven-plugin, to:

1. perform preliminary cleanup of the destination folder [clean phase]
2. copy the zip file (from my local machine) into a specific project folder [prepare-package phase]
3. extract those files [prepare-package phase]

**The problem:** Although it works fine when the zip file is on my computer, I don't seem to be able to find a Maven plugin that allows me to download that file when it's situated into a shared folder. The closest I have found so far was the [maven-download-plugin](https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin). It has a *wget* goal, but of course it works on standard http protocol, not smb.

Any hints/advices?